# How to change data-toggle button background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to give custom color code for this toggle button instead of danger and success

```html
 <input type="checkbox"  class="" 
      data-toggle="toggle" 
      data-onstyle="danger" 
      data-offstyle="success" 
      data-on="Blocked" 
      data-off="Active"  />
```

Comment: HTML checkbox can't be styled...

Comment: Is there any way to do this

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp